# Vue.js: Outputting contents of an array one element at a time with delay

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js

In my Vue instance's data property, I have an array of strings.

```
data() {
  return { myArray: [] }
}
```

This array is filled with words of a sentence. For example:

```
['Hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'foo']
```

I would like to output the sentence to a paragraph tag in my template one word at a time, with a 1 second delay in between, similar to how a teleprompter would work:

[0 sec] - Hi

[1 sec] - Hi my

[2 sec] - Hi my name

[3 sec] - Hi my name is

[4 sec] - Hi my name is foo

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should first try to write some code on your own and then ask for help in case of problems - please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @picard yeah but whats the fun in that :) It's been a slow day in the `vue.js` tag. (JK :)

Comment: @Picard haha, my attempt involved making a new array and string-interpolating that to the template, while moving contents of the first array to the new one with a delay. Did not think that was worthy of posting. Thank you for the link though, I will take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` and add a word on each iteration:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    array: ['Hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'foo'],
    string: '' // here your string will be stored
  },
  methods: {
    appendWords: function() {
      const it = this.array[Symbol.iterator](); // convenient for yeilding values
      const int = setInterval(() => { // time interval
        const next = it.next(); // next value 
        if (!next.done) { // done = true when the end of array reached
          this.string += ' ' + next.value; // concatenate word to the string
        } else {
          clearInterval(int); // when done - clear interval
        }
      }, 1000) // interval duration, 1s
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.appendWords(); // invoke function when ready
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ string }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for teaching me about iterators in javascript!

Comment: I love how this is not quite what he asked for but accepted lol :) Damned users! And literal programmers (me).

Comment: @BertEvans I just saw your answer! My bad, I was unclear in my description. I wanted a teleprompter-feel, which is what this solution gives.

Comment: @BertEvans he asked to "output the sentence to a paragraph tag in my template one word at a time", it's pretty clear. I guess you was misled by this 'timeline' output simply.

Comment: @KevinShi I was making fun of myself guys :) I interpreted the question example output *extremely* literally.

Answer (score 1):

Code

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    base: ['Hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'foo'],
    timed: []
  },
  mounted(){
    this.base.forEach((item, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.timed.push(`[${i} sec] - ${this.base.slice(0, i + 1).join(" ")}`)
      }, i * 1000)
    })
  }
})
```

Template

```
<div id="app">
  <p v-for="time in timed">{{time}}</p>
</div>
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/PjYKyW).

**Edit**

So, for fun, I thought about how you might go about making a teleprompter simulation in javascript. This is pretty naive, but works for the amount of time that I've put into it.

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    lines: [
      'Hi, my name is Foo. I am a literal', 
      'programmer. This is a teleprompter',
      'simulation. These lines should all',
      'be about the same length. There are ',
      'different strategies for making that',
      'happen.'
    ],
    show:[]
  },
  mounted(){
    let currentIndex = 0
    
    this.$el.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
      this.show.push(this.lines[++currentIndex])
    })
    this.show.push(this.lines[0])
  }
})
```

```css
@keyframes revealText {
  0% {
    width:0%;

   }
  100% {
    width:100%;

  }
}

#app{
  width: 500px; 
  margin: auto
}

h1 {
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: revealText 5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1 v-for="line in show">{{line}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @kevinshi I was curious and played around with this. Have a look if you care :)

Comment: This looks nice.

Comment: @wostex thanks! CSS is really not my forte. I expect there is a decent way to do this with transition-group or something too.